# Adobe Flex Builder 3 : Cannot add any method/function to any class of an existing project?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe

I'm totally new to Adobe Flex Builder 3.
I've been assigned a fully functional project but when I want to add the simplest function to any class, I always got the same error :

> Call to a possibly undefined method through a reference with static type

For example, in some random class there is a function defined like this :

```
public function GetID() :String     { return m_strID; }
```

If I try to define a new one like below :

```
public function GetIDFoo() :String      { return m_strID; }
```

And then I try to call both of them like this :

```
trace ("This line is ok : " + oPhysicalScreen.GetID());
trace ("This line gives me an error : " + oPhysicalScreen.GetIDFoo());
```

Any clue?

Regards,
Michel

PS: full code where I do the call :

```
public function UpdatePhysicalScreenData(oScreenNode:XML):void 
{
    if (m_vPhysicalScreens == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var oScreenList:CMultyList = m_rBasicScreen.GetPhysicalScreensPanel().GetScreenList();

    var oPhysicalScreen:CPhysicalScreen = FindPhysicalScreen(oScreenNode.@id);

    if (oPhysicalScreen == null)
    {
        oPhysicalScreen = new CPhysicalScreen();
        {
            oPhysicalScreen.Initialize(oScreenNode.@id);
            oPhysicalScreen.SetInfo(oScreenNode.@info);

            var eList:uint = oScreenNode.@list;

            if (eList < SCREENS_LIST_TITLES.length)
            {
                oScreenList.SelectCurrentList(eList);
            }
            else
            {
                oScreenList.SelectCurrentList(2);//Test
            }
            var oNewEntry:CEntry = oScreenList.CreateEntryInCurrentList(oPhysicalScreen.GetID() + " " + oPhysicalScreen.GetInfo(), oPhysicalScreen);
            //var oNewEntry:CEntry = oScreenList.CreateEntryInCurrentList(oPhysicalScreen.GetDisplayName(), oPhysicalScreen);

            oNewEntry.ChangeTextColor(CPanelPhysicalScreens.STATE_COLORS[oPhysicalScreen.GetState()]);
        }

        m_vPhysicalScreens.AddAtEnd(oPhysicalScreen);
    } 

    if (oPhysicalScreen != null)
    {
        //should never be null but ...
        trace ("UpdatePhysicalScreenData : " + oPhysicalScreen.GetID() + " " + oPhysicalScreen.GetInfo() + " State : "+ oPhysicalScreen.GetState());
        trace ("UpdatePhysicalScreenData : " + oPhysicalScreen.GetIDFoo() + " " + oPhysicalScreen.GetInfo() + " State : "+ oPhysicalScreen.GetState());
    }
    oPhysicalScreen.SetDiffusionCode(oScreenNode.@diffusionCode);
    oPhysicalScreen.SetCurrentSequence((int)(oScreenNode.@currentSequence));
    oPhysicalScreen.SetIsAlive(oScreenNode.@alive == "true");
}
```

Start of class definition :

```
public class CPhysicalScreen
{
public static var STATE_UNUSED          :uint = 0;
public static var STATE_SYNC            :uint = 1;
public static var STATE_UNSYNC          :uint = 2;
public static var STATE_KO              :uint = 3;

public static var STATE_MAX_WAIT_TIME   :uint = 5000;


private var m_strID             :String;
private var m_eState            :uint;
private var m_strInfo           :String;
private var m_strDiffusionCode  :String;
private var m_uiCurrentSequence :int;
private var m_bIsAlive          :Boolean;


public function CPhysicalScreen()
{
    super();

    m_strID             = null;
    m_eState            = STATE_UNUSED;
    m_strInfo           = "";
    m_strDiffusionCode  = "";
    m_uiCurrentSequence = 0;
    m_bIsAlive          = false;
}


public function GetID()                             :String     { return m_strID; }
public function GetIDFoo()                              :String     { return m_strID; }
```

...

Comment: Just a thought, but what is the type of oPhysicalScreen when you're invoking the method?  How is it declared in the class?  Is it possible oPhysicalScreen is referenced as an Interface type where you're invoking "GetIDFoo()", and the Interface doesn't include the method you introduced?

Comment: can you add a full code?? the basic function definition and prototyping seem to be fine.

Comment: I'v added the full function code where I do the call.
And the the start of the class definition...

Comment: What confuses me is that everything that exist works fine, but anything I'd like to add won't work!?

Comment: Is CPhysicalScreen in a different project from the class that has the function UpdatePhysicalScreenData?  You package locales and imports were not included... (I'm going to guess that my question will give you the solution to your problem?).  Best of luck -- jeremy

Comment: Can you break the existing code by changing a function that works? If that change is also not changing anything, you must be editing the wrong source files. Maybe those classes are in a .swc too?

Comment: @jeremy.mooer : 
CPhysicalScreen is indeed in a different project. But there is an import at the top : import CanraCommon.Data.CPhysicalScreen;
Could it be that somehow the import does not update itself? (Remember I'm new to AS and Flex ;-))

@frankhermes :I just tried and it seems that modification in other part of the project are not applied.

It seems I need to build it explicitly. Can you tell me how to do that? I thought it was automatic?

Comment: @frankhermes : I noticed that there is a "CanraCommon.swc" in the lib directory of my CanraController. I did a copy/paste of the one in the bin dir of my CanraCommon to CanraControler and it's working!! :-)
Now: what should I do to make that copy automatically?

Comment: you could add the bin folder of that Canra project to the library path of your other project. That way, a change in the source of the swc file will automatically go into your other project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, thanks to @jeremy.mooer and @frankhermes :-)

In project properties : ActionScript Build Path : Library path tab.

There were existing project librairies.

A "lib" folder with some swc files in it. Theses swc come from another project wich is needed.

I added a new project (Add project button), then I selected wich project were building needed swc files.

Now when I make changes in these other projects, they are made available to my main project.

I think these got unlinked when the project was given to me...

Thanks to people who helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

The class CPhysicalScreen that you posted does not contain a closing `}`
Also you may have to wrap it in a package.

Comment: Thanks for you input but as stated, it is just the start of the class definition. Also everything is in a package.

Comment: Usually this kind of error is do to the braces not being correct. In fact the code you posted for where the call is being done i see an extra set of braces not that, that is the problem but, it is something you may want to review. Without you posting the full code I can not really say much more.

Comment: Well you have to understand that everything in the project works well. I just did a duplicate of the "GetID" function name "GetIDFoo".
Then, where "GetID" is called, I call "GetIDFoo"
Really I don't touch anything else :-/